# Getting custom Wordpress pages with url parameters indexed by google

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, wordpress, google-programmable-search-engine

I have a Wordpress site set up that connects to a third party db to display data (widgets).

I have one template set up that will display a list of widgets: https://mywebsite.com/widgets

Clicking through on a particular widget will bring you to a page like this: https://mywebsite.com/widgets/widgets/widget?cat=promo&sku=10034

So the widget information is queried based on the url arguments supplied.

This works well, but I'm having trouble getting my Google Custom Search (or Google at all) to pick up on these pages. Ideally, I'd like it to index all the widgets listed on the .../widgets list.

In the Google Search Console, I can navigate to Crawl > URL Parameters and I see my widget parameters listed, with my total number of widgets. I click edit, and made sure to select that it specifies content, and that Googlebot should crawl every url.

So, based on that it seems Googlebot is aware of these pages, but I cannot get them to appear in search results. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Google usually only chooses to index URLs that are well linked to and have unique content.   The parameters themselves probably are no the problem.   Is the content on these URLs unique?   Does each have a unique title and meta description?  Do you link to each widget from multiple places on your site?

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller, the content on each of these pages is absolutely unique, and they should appear on at least a couple of landing pages/promotions which do show up in search results. I use a Wordpress filter to override the page title with data from my query, but I think there may be some gaps in the meta content. Is this alone enough to prevent them from being listed?

Comment: Your landing pages and promotions are likely not well linked.   They won't have the power to get things they link to indexed.